# Access nested object property and update its value through Generic method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I want create a generic method which will access a nested object property and update its value  passed as argument.

```
This is my data structure
 var student = {
  name: 'Tom',
  address: {
    pincode: 43301,
    street: '12th Main',
    city: 'Some city',
  },
  marks: {
    sub1: 111,
    sub2: 222
  }
}
```

This is my skeleton of the generic method

```
updatProperty(student, 'marks.sub1', 125) {
  // this method should return student object with marks.sub1 to be 125
}
```

[I have refereed this link , but this will only return me a value](https://gist.github.com/jasonrhodes/2321581)

Comment: You might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with reduce method, where you check if current value exists and if length of your string key is equal to current element and then change value.

```js
var student = {"name":"Tom","address":{"pincode":43301,"street":"12th Main","city":"Some city"},"marks":{"sub1":111,"sub2":222}}

function updatProperty(obj, key, value) {
  key.split('.').reduce((r, e, i, a) => {
    if (r[e] && a.length - 1 == i) r[e] = value
    return r[e] || {}
  }, obj)
}

updatProperty(student, 'marks.sub1', 125);
console.log(student)
```

Comment: This is the best solution.

Comment: Awesome!, Exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. I would go ahead and do it like this. THis way you can pass an array in of the value you want to change (i.e. `['marks', 'sub1']`) and it will change whatever value you want. See the below example of how I change `student.marks.sub1` and `student.address.city`:

```js
var student = {
  name: 'Tom',
  address: {
    pincode: 43301,
    street: '12th Main',
    city: 'Some city',
  },
  marks: {
    sub1: 111,
    sub2: 222
  }
}

function updateProperty(student, keys, value) {
    obj = student;

    for(var i=0; i<keys.length-1; i++){
        obj = obj[keys[i]];
    }

    obj[keys[i]] = value;
    
    return student;
}


console.log(updateProperty(student, ['marks', 'sub1'], 125));
console.log(updateProperty(student, ['address', 'city'], 'New York'));
```

Comment: Thanks Cory, but I want the path to my object to be dynamic. It should be able to handle any level of nesting

Comment: @LakshmanKumar .. I've updated my answer to make it dynamic. Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

[Immediate solution] 
I would suggest something like:

```
function updatProperty(obj, propPath, value) {

    if(!propPath) return false;

    const keys = propPath.split('.');
    let pointer = obj,
        validPath = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length && validPath; i++) {

        let key = keys[i];

        if(i === (keys.length - 1)) pointer[key] = value;
        else {
            if(!pointer[key]) validPath = false;
            else pointer = pointer[key];
        }
    }

    return validPath;
}
```

[Explaining] 
Following you function signature, I reason by

1. spliting the "path string" by '.' and therefore get an array in
   order to navigate through the object.
2. Create a loop by using the
   `keys` and navigate/ validate the object till reach the wanted prop - if the path is valid to the object, everything goes ok otherwise the loop stops and the function returns false.

Something I assumed but not mentioned by you is the function returned value - true if everything goes well and false if not (no `propPath` or if the object is "incorrect").

Hope it helps.